# Error messages are not in the correct order

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my spring MVC validation, the order of my error messages changes randomly, I would like the messages to be in the same order as they appear on the page.

My AccountForm.java class looks like:

```
@NotNull(message = "Account name cannot be empty.")
@Size(min=3, max=50, message="Account name must be between 3 and 50 characters long.")
private String accountName;

@NotNull(message = "Company name cannot be empty.")
@Size(min=3, max=50, message="Company name must be between 3 and 50 characters long.")
private String companyName;
```

And I also append some custom errors in my controller:

```
   public ModelAndView create(@Valid AccountForm accountForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("accounts/new");
    mav.addObject("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
    mav.addObject("accountForm", accountForm);

    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        if(accountService.findByAccountName(accountForm.getAccountName()) != null) {
            bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("accountName", "Account name is already is use"));
        }
        ..
        ..
    }

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors() {
      return mav;
    }

    ..
```

When I hit submit on the form, the order of the messages keeps changing.

I render the errors in my view using:

```
        <#list errors as error>
            <li>${error.defaultMessage}</li>
        </#list>
```

Can this be fixed?

Comment: out of the 1800 questions you accepted only 60%? :) Darn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is achieved via Validation Groups and Spring supportes it. You are using **@Valid** annotation, but it should have been **@Validated** in order to use Validation Groups:

```
 public ModelAndView submitSearch(@Validated(value={OrderChecks.class}) @ModelAttribute("SearchStringBackingObject") final SearchStringBackingObject backingObject
```

OrderChecks.class:

```
 @GroupSequence(value={NotEmptyGroup.class, LengthCheckGroup.class, DiacriticeCheckGroup.class, EmailValidationGroup.class, EmailLengthValidationGroup.class,
    Email3EntriesValidationGroup.class, EntityAlreadyExistsValidatorGroup.class, Default.class})
 public interface OrderChecks {}
```

And inside the backing Object:

```
 @NotBlank(groups=NotEmptyGroup.class)
@Length(max=25, groups=LengthCheckGroup.class)
@DiacriticeCheck(groups=DiacriticeCheckGroup.class)
private String firstname="";
```

where each of the Entries in the @GroupSequence is an interface.

**EDIT**

So if you want the account name to be validated first, then you create an interface for it:

```
public interface AccountNameGroup{}
```

Then inside the Validation Group interface you this is going to be the first interface:

```
@GroupSequence(value={AccountNameGroup.class, the rest of groups})
public interface OrderOfGroups{}

And of course inside the Controller you specify the @Validated annotation with the OrderOFGroups interface.
```

In this way the Account Name will be validated first

Comment: so in my case I have account name, company name, email, password.  I have to create a group for each one?

Comment: man that is allot of boilerplate code for simple ordering, go java! :)

Comment: @Blankman yup probably you're right, but I do not know a better one. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this way works for case with 1 field. For many fields it not work  "parallely", next group will be used when all errors from precedent groups  are fixed

Comment: @Ruslan I honestly do not recall much, it's been 8 years since I posted this answer

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and tried a lot. I think there is now standard way of doing this in JSR-303.
  This can be achieved using [groups](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using) (which I personally dont like) or by defining `<form:error>` is desired sequence.