# global form:errors field sequence

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp, validation

At the beginning of my form, I have a global form:errors :

```
<form:form method="post" action="updateMainContact" modelAttribute="mainContact">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
```

In my form, I have three fields in this specific order : **Phone, Cell, Fax** :

```
<th><label for="mainContactPhoneLabel">Phone Number:<br>9999999999</label></th> 
    <td><form:input path="phone" type="integer" size="10" maxlength="10"  />
<th><label for="mainContactFaxLabel">Fax:<br>9999999999</label></th> 
    <td><form:input path="fax" type="integer" size="15" maxlength="15" />
<th><label for="mainContactEmailLabel">Email:</label></th> 
    <td><form:input path="email" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" /></td>
```

When I force a typemismatch error all three fields, the result sequence **is ALWAYS Cell, Fax then Phone**. 
Why is that ? How can I make the order follow my field sequence on the screen (**Phone, Cell, Fax**) ?

Note that I cannot have individual form:errors tags because I do not have enough space per field to put the form:errors tag, which is why I have them all on top.

**EDIT** I want all error messages in the same "errorblock". Listing them individually at top :

```
<form:errors path="phone" cssClass="errorblock" />
<form:errors path="cell" cssClass="errorblock" />
<form:errors path="fax" cssClass="errorblock" />
```

doesn't help me because it creates a an errorblock per error message.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after a lot of searching on the internet, I've finally found a way to get the result I wanted :

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="mainContact">                   
    <c:if test="${errors.errorCount > 0}">
        <div class="errorblock">
            <c:forEach items="${errors.fieldErrors}" var="errorList">
                <c:if test="${errorList.field=='phone'}">
                   <form:errors path="phone" /><br>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:forEach items="${errors.fieldErrors}" var="errorList">
                <c:if test="${errorList.field=='cell'}">
                   <form:errors path="cell" /><br>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>                            
            <c:forEach items="${errors.fieldErrors}" var="errorList">
                <c:if test="${errorList.field=='fax'}">
                   <form:errors path="fax" /><br>
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>                            
        </div>                              
    </c:if>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

This code puts each error message on an individual line in the same "error" block.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to use path for each single field.

```
<form:errors path="phone" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
<form:errors path="cell" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
<form:errors path="fax" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
```

You can also try solution with groups (see [Error messages are not in the correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804879/error-messages-are-not-in-the-correct-order)). But it doesn't seems good choice to me.

**EDIT**:

Why not use one whole `div` around errors with class `errorblock` like this?

```
<div class="errorblock">
    <form:errors path="phone" cssClass="" element="div" />
    <form:errors path="cell" cssClass="" element="div" />
    <form:errors path="fax" cssClass="" element="div" />
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it creates a small red table for each message.I want all messages to be in the same "block", which form:errors path="*" does. 
I've also tried putting them in a global <div> to no avail.